# Is there an excel VBA line of code I can add to check if any values in a column have changed since the last time the macro was ran?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main work area. This main work area is setup with so that a bunch of different sections can be shown or not shown in the main area based on checkboxes. We run a Macro (via a button) every time we are ready to send the clients updates. I want to add in our main macro a prompt/warning to pop up ONLY IF someone has changed the checkboxes. I have a column the boxes are tied to with "TRUE"/"FALSE" values.

Can i set the range for my column say  $V:$10:$V:$90 so that if any of those values are not the same as they were the last time this macro was ran, it will prompt the user?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Alternatively, there are several sheets in this workbook. I could essentially copy/paste the column range i want to a new area, and then compare the two columns everytime the macro is ran. If they are not the same, then pop up a message box. But I am hoping there is a way to just analyze the data.

Thanks

Comment: You could take a copy of the output data and paste to a hidden sheet. Then simply make a column next to your front-page data with the formula: =V10=HiddenSheet!A1 to check for matches

Comment: I could do that BUT i am specifically needing some VBA code to PROMPT the user with a message box if the values in the column have changed and they click the macro to send out the update.  I have read about loading both ranges into memory array and loop the arrays and compare and this would work perfectly but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: It's not that hard, dont worry. See https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/           I would still save the output data to a hidden sheet as arrays are only saved in memory while the code is running, arrays are the superior method (in terms of speed) to do calculations. What you need to do is create an 2 column array with frontpage data in column 1 and data from hidden sheet in column 2. Then simply loop over the array (see Lbound to Ubound) to compare each value and return a msgbox whenever they are not matching.

Comment: You could also just do as in my first comment and loop through the true/false statements and return a msgbox if there are any false matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this, along with the other posters help and come up with this solution:

```
Dim x, y, i As Long, ii As Long, msg As String

x = Range("V8:V120")
y = Range("W8:W120")
msg = "The 2 ranges are identical"
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
For ii = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
If x(i, ii) <> y(i, ii) Then
msg = "The email body has changed and not been saved."
End If
Next
Next

If msg = "The email body has changed and not been saved." Then
MsgBox ("The email body has changed and not been saved.")
End If
```